# Adding image to button via tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button, python-imaging-library, photoimage

This is the code...

```
from tkinter import *
import PIL

count = 0

def click():
    global count
    count+=1
    print(count)

window = Tk()

photo = PhotoImage(file='Flanderson.png')

button = Button(window,
                text="Draw A Card",
                command=click,
                font=("Comic Sans",30),
                fg="#00FF00",
                bg="black",
                activeforeground="#00FF00",
                activebackground="black",
                state=ACTIVE,
                image=photo,
                compound='bottom')
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

So I am trying to download add an image to my button but "PhotoImage not defined" error occurs also "No module named PIL"

I installed Pillow via pip but nothing changes

Comment: The code works fine and cannot reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `"PhotoImage not defined"` because you might be using older version of Tkinter. And also PhotoImage class only supports  PGM, PPM, GIF, PNG format image formats.
so you should write:

```
photo = PhotoImage(file='Flanderson.gif')
```

and if you want to use other format, you can use this:

```
Image.open("Flanderson.jpg")
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
```

so the final code will be:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

count = 0

def click():
    global count
    count+=1
    print(count)

window = Tk()

load = Image.open("Flanderson.jpg")
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)

button = Button(window,
                text="Draw A Card",
                command=click,
                font=("Comic Sans",30),
                fg="#00FF00",
                bg="black",
                activeforeground="#00FF00",
                activebackground="black",
                state=ACTIVE,
                image=photo,
                compound='bottom')
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

for `"No module named PIL"` make sure you installed the pillow module. If it doesn't work try to restart your software and install Pillow module again by typing `pip install Pillow` in command prompt I was also having this problem earlier.

Comment: _"PhotoImage class only supports GIF and PGM/PPM image formats. "_ - modern versions of tkinter have supported png for a few years now.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I have fixed it after reading the [documentation](https://tkdocs.com/pyref/photoimage.html)

Comment: *"PhotoImage not defined"* does not mean that the image format is not supported. It means that the function is not defined.